# How is for comprehension returning None on comparison?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, max, scala-option

How is a below printed as `None` as the max is `3` here

```
val firstNum: Option[Int] = None
val secondNum: Option[Int] = Some(3)

val a = for {
  f <- firstNum
  s <- secondNum

} yield Math.max(f, s)

println(a)
```

output

```
None
```

Comment: Because first `<-` is actually a `flatMap` method, and it is called only if the `Option` is present (its value is `Some`).

Comment: It's because `option` obey all Monads law including left identity, meaning `None.flatMap(f)` always returns None.

Comment: okay but, firstNum when flattened, it is still None but the other one, secondNum after flattened, it will be 3.. and then 3 is the max ..

Comment: After firstNum is flattened and you get None, the evaluation stops there. When you attempt to call flatMap again on None, you still get None, so everything after "f <- firstNum" doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in comment section was mentioned, your are using `for-comprehension` construction, which under the hood invokes `flatMap` method, which according to left identity monad law always works like this:  `None.flatmap(f) == None`.

If you you want to find max between two `Option[Int]` and ignore if any of them absent, try to:

```
val firstNum: Option[Int] = None
val secondNum: Option[Int] = Some(3)
​
println(List(firstNum, secondNum).flatten.max)
```

Scatie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/UbCy36hHS3iVLKEdqzqUCw

Comment: okay, one just doubt , so at the end in the yield Math.max(f, s), how are the values passed there,  it is not as `Math.max(None, 3)` ?

Comment: @supernatural Excuse me, I'm afraid I'm not following. Math.max does not accept Option, your example won't compile.

Comment: @supernatural If you de-sugar `for-yield` it will be : firstNum.flatMap(f => secondNum.map(s => Math.max(f, s)))

Comment: ok, so if s is None then it will only return f

Comment: and if f is None, it wont go the first map itself and return None

Answer (score 4):

Just to add on top of the great answer by @IvanKurchenko. `.max` might throw an exception in case there are no elements in the `List`. For example:

```
List[Option[Int]](None).flatten.max
```

will throw an exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.max
```

Instead, you can use [`maxOption`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/IterableOnce.scala#L958):

```
List(Some(3), None).flatten.maxOption
```

which will provide `Some(3)`, and

```
List[Option[Int]](None).flatten.max
```

will provide `None`.